# Why this concurrent execution always give me the same trace?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to understand concurrent execution in Java, but given this code :

```
class Inter extends Thread {
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("Starting..."); 
        try {
            sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted."); }
        System.out.println("Finished."); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inter hi = new Inter();
        hi.start();
        System.out.println("Sending interruption..."); 
        hi.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Sent."); 
    }
}
```

I don't know why always give me this trace :

```
Sending interruption...
Sent.
Starting...
Interrupted.
Finished.
```

No matter how many times I run :

```
$ java Inter
```

As fars as I know in Java, when we execute the start() method in a new thread, the execution of this thread starts.

So , since the main thread and the Inter thread are concurrently executed, why can't be this a possible trace, ?

```
Starting..
Sending interruption..
Sent
Interrupted
Finished
```

Comment: try adding `sleep` after calling `start()`

Comment: Nothing in a computer is instant and starting a thread takes time. The first thread might take 50 micro-seconds which is perhaps 100,000 clock cycles.

Comment: It should be possible, but probably less likely. It all depends on when the JVM passes control from the main thread to the second thread, which is not something you can rely on, unless you add synchronization. I actually got a different output - `Sending interruption...
Starting...
Sent.
Interrupted.
Finished.`

Comment: @PeterLawrey So, the main thread is always first executed ? In the case that not exist mechanisms of synchronization.

Comment: @Eran, so it depends on the scheduler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, since the main thread and the Inter thread are concurrently executed, why can't be this a possible trace?

Yes, it can. If you run your program a thousand times, most probably you will have that output at least once.

It's up to the operating system thread scheduler to arrange the threads execution in order to give that possible output, but we have no control over the scheduler. Hence, the importance of properly designing your code to prevent race conditions.